# Оптимизация алгоритма вычисления "разности" списков IP-диапазонов

Tags: алгоритм, java

Здравствуйте!

**Понятия**

- `IPAddressRange` - Диапазон IP-адресов, задан в виде network/mask или ipFirst, ipLast (но в итоге все равно приводится ко второму виду). Так же подразумевается, как некоторое множество (совокупность) последовательных (упорядоченных) чисел (числовая интерпретация IP-адресов), заданная двумя значениями, первым и последним из диапазона *(прощу прощения за сложное пояснение)*
- `List<IPAddressRange>` - Список IP-диапазонов (множеств)

**Что имеем:**

- Список IP-диапазонов - **база**
- Список IP-диапазонов - **исключения**
- Функция выполняющая вычитание множеств и возвращающая ноль, один или два диапазона
- Язык программирования - Java

**Что нужно сделать:**

Из первого списка вычесть все вхождения второго списка (т.е. обычная разность множеств), алгоритм составлен (но еще не реализован), базовые классы и методы для реализации имеются.

Примерно алгоритм выглядит так:

- Выбираем последовательно элементы из списка **исключения**
- Для каждого элемента из списка **база** проверяем, входит ли выбранный элемент списка **исключения** в множество (сравниваем границы)
- Если не входит - добавляем во временный список элемент из **база**
- Если входит - выполняем разность множеств
- "Отработавший" элемента списка **база** заменяется на новый(е) (два случая рассматривается: границы элемента из **исключения** больше или равны границам элемента из **база** (получаем 0 (обе границы - **>=**) или 1 (одна из границ - **>=**) новый элемент), границы элемента из **исключения** **<** границ элемента из **база** (получаем 2 новых элемента))
- Новые элементы добавляются во временный список
- Элемент списка **исключения** удаляется, когда пройдет все элементы списка **база**, элементы из временного списка переносятся в список **база**, процедура повторяется

Хотелось бы оптимизировать мое решение, открыт для идей и наставлений.

Comment: Прошу прощения, что Вы на самом деле хотите ? 

Может быть принять решение (Permit/Deny) пропустить или нет пакет (или соединение) по его IP ?

Comment: Я хочу то, что описал и не более того.

Comment: Комментарий могу оставить здесь только, пожалуй. Уважаемый, @avp, Вы видимо не совсем поняли задачу. Мне не нужно проверять вхождения в один или в другой список, мне необходимо выполнить диссекцию (разность двух множеств) элементов из двух списков. Прочитайте пожалуйста мой алгоритм.

Comment: Прочитал, понял, хотел как лучше - получилось, как всегда...

Comment: Что получилось "как всегда"? Простите, возможно, я просто не понял ваш алгоритм, но никого ведь я не обвинял.

Comment: "Как всегда" - это шутка (из В. Черномырдина). Если серьезно, то я подумал, что Вам надо решить конкретную задачу. 

Обсудить Ваш алгоритм (или другой), вычисляющий разность множеств, представляемых в виде списка диапазонов, безусловно нужно. Только подумаю вначале. И Java (мне кажется) здесь ни при чем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Разделить IPv4 и IPv6 интервалы и обрабатывать их отдельно
2. Надо понимать, что каждый конец интервала - это просто long числа. Предположим, у нас есть реализация для получения такого числа для любого из концов.
3. Предполагаем, что интервалы заданы верно (first <= last)
4. Сортируем списки интервалов по их началам как long числам
5. Идём по спискам по порядку по обоим спискам. Почти как в известной задачке про книги на полках и попутно строим третий список. Не забываем о возможности пересечений соседних интервалов в обоих списках.

Сложность зависит от типа применяемой сортировки, но она будет лучше, чем M * N в случае, если M и N достаточно велики (понятно, что если списки 3 на 2, то быстрее будет просто всех со всеми сравнить).

Comment: IPv6 у нас нету. Только 4й.
Интервалы заданы верно. Каждый конец интервала и есть long число.
Сложно себе представляю данный алгоритм. Например, если имеем базу 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 и 10.10.10.0 - 10.10.10.255, а исключение 10.10.10.10 - 10.10.10.20: исключаем из первого элемента базы - получаем два подмножества, но из второго ведь тоже надо исключить, как мы тогда пойдем параллельно?

Comment: Ну так и что? Мы будем оставать на первом исключении столько, сколько нужно и исключим его из обоих баз.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как оно будет происходить. Можете поподробнее описать, на примере вот таких двух множеств: "база" - 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 и 10.10.10.0 - 10.10.10.255, "исключения" - 10.10.10.10 - 10.10.10.20 и 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.10.50

Comment: И еще один практический вопрос. Каково реальное количество этих диапазонов в списках ? Порядок величин (десятки, тысячи, сотни тысяч ...).

Comment: Диапазонов может быть несколько десятков, а вот процедуру такую, возможно, придется проделывать еще десяток-другой раз.

Comment: Для десятков я бы вообще не заморачивался с подобными алгоритмами. Тупо перебираем все диапазоны **исключений**. Попал в диапазон - исключен. Не попал - ищем в диапазонах базы. Попал - годится. Если не нашли ни в исключениях ни в базе - отбрасываем. 

Просто я делал такую задачу - все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Как обещал в своем комментарии подумал. [[[[@cy6erGn0m](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)](/users/335/cy6ergn0m) в своем ответе (на мой взгляд) оптимальный алгоритм описал.

Плюс к этому я **обязательно** добавил бы после сортировки диапазонов списка (п. 4 у [[[[@cy6erGn0m](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)) **СЛИЯНИЕ пересекающихся диапазонов**. Это проводится за один проход списка и может сильно сократить его размер (вплоть до одного элемента, как в Вашем комментарии: "база" - 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 и 10.10.10.0 - 10.10.10.255). Более того (как мне кажется) реализация п.5 тоже станет проще.

Далее за один параллельный проход обоих списков из множества базы исключаем элементы множества исключений.

Количество операций можно оценить в N*log(N) + M*log(M) + M + N + m + n  (m, n - количество диапазонов после слияния).

Comment: Спасибо! Чего-то я об этом думал, но потом откинул эту мысль. Слияние ведь действительно все упростит.